# Integral computation involving $\sin^2 x$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, fourier-series

I am attempting to find the Fourier series for $\sin^2x$ but am getting stuck.

For the value of $a_0$, I am trying to do it as follows:

$$ \frac 1{2\pi}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}(\frac 12 -\frac 12\cos(2x))dx$$

$$ =\frac 1{2\pi}\left[\frac 12x-\frac 14\sin(2x)\right]_{-\frac \pi2}^{\frac \pi2}$$

However, when I evaluate this, it does not come out to be exactly 1/2. Why is this happening?

Since for this function $f(x)$ = $f(-x)$, there will be no $b_n$ term (the coefficients for the sine series). However there will be an $a_n$ term, for the cosine part.

For that:

$$ a_n=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\sin^2x\cos(nx)\,dx$$

Please evaluate those two integrals fully and with steps, for me to understand, and why am I wrong in the first integral trying to evaluate $a_0$? And how do I integrate the second integral trying to find $a_n$?

This is quite urgent. Thank you.

Comment: Because that integral is trying to find the constant term in the fourier series of $sin^2x$, which works out to be: $\frac 12 - \frac 12*cos(2x)$, therefore I need to get $\frac 12$. How else can I get it? And how should I proceed with the second integral? Is it correct for what I am trying to get?

Answer (score 0):

By using the trig identity:

$$\sin^2{t} = \frac{1-\cos{2t}}{2},$$ your integral becomes:

$$a_n = \frac{1}{2} \int^{\pi/2}_{-\pi/2} (\cos{nx} - \cos{2x}\cos{nx}) \, dx, $$

which may be splitted in two terms: $$a_n = \frac{1}{2} (I_1 - I_2).$$ Then:

$$I_1 = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} \pi & n = 0 \\ \frac{2 \sin{\frac{n\pi}{2}}}{n}  & n = 0  \end{array} \right., $$

and for evaluating $I_2$ you may use the chain rule for the integration of a product of two functions when $n \neq \pm 2$:

$$I_2 = \int^{\pi/2}_{-\pi/2} \cos{2x} \cos{nx} \, dx = \left.\frac{\sin{2x} \cos{nx}}{2} \right|_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} +  \int^{\pi/2}_{-\pi/2} \frac{\sin{2x}}{2} n \sin{nx} \, dx = 0+   \left. \left(-\frac{n}{2} \frac{\cos{2x}}{2} \sin{nx}\right)\right|^{\pi/2}_{-\pi/2} + \int^{\pi/2}_{\pi/2} \frac{n^2}{4} \cos{2x} \cos{nx} = \frac{1}{2} \sin{\frac{n\pi}{2}} + \frac{n^2}{4} I_2.$$

On the other hand, if $n = \pm 2$ you have:

$$I_2 = \int^{\pi/2}_{-\pi/2} \cos^2{2x} \, dx = \int^{\pi/2}_{\pi/2} \frac{1+\cos{4x}}{2} \, dx =\pi/2 $$

then:

$$I_2 = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} \pi/2 & n = \pm 2 \\ \frac{2 n \sin{\frac{n\pi}{2}}}{n^2-4}  & n \neq \pm 2  \end{array} \right., $$

and now you can solve your problem.

Cheers!

Comment: Could you please write the evaluated integral in a single line, for me to understand? Such as: $a_n = ...$ It would be of utmost use. That was helpful Dmoreno. But what about the first part of my question, regarding finding the value of $a_0$? How can I find that? Also, what were the terms you substitued for u, v, u' and v' in the integration using the chain rule? I'm sorry, but I find these quite confusing. Thank you so much. EDIT: URGENT - The expanded, Fourier series of sin^2 x is: $\frac 12 + \frac 12cos(2x)$. How can I calculate $a_n$ as $1/2$? That is the reason I was doing the integral